# Update Fragment UI with data passed from Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-bundle

**My Requirement :**

My `MainActivity` receives data from other app. `MainActivity` is listed as `shareable`.

Now, I need to pass this data to a `fragment` in `MainActivity` and update the `fragment's` `textview`.

In **MainActivity.java :** here I'm handling the received data (which is a URL) in `handleSendText` method.

```
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action) && type != null) {
        if ("text/plain".equals(type)) {
            handleSendText(intent); // Handle text being sent
        }
    }
}
```

In `handleSendText`, I'm trying to create a bundle and pass that data to my fragment.

```
void handleSendText(Intent intent) {
    String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
    if (sharedText != null) {
   
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("url", sharedText);

   // set Fragmentclass Arguments
        AddTab fragobj = new AddTab(); //AddTab() is my Fragment class's name
        fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
    }
```

In **Fragment class :** In its onCreateView()

```
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
//some code

       Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

        if(bundle!=null) {
     
            String sharedUrl = getArguments().getString("url");
     
            textBox.setText(sharedUrl);

            inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add, container, false);
            // to update the UI to reflect changes, I'm trying the 
           // above line. Is it right?            
        }
```

**1)** The problem is the control is never reaching inside of the `if` loop, which means `bundle` is always returning `NULL`.

**2)** Moreover, if I don't receive the data from other app. I want to leave my `editText` empty, so I have to perform this check.How can I make that happen?

**3)** Moreover, from `setArgument`'s [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setArguments(android.os.Bundle)), I learnt that it should be called before the fragment has been attached to its activity. Then how can I reflect the changes in the Fragment's UI?

> **public void setArguments (Bundle args)**
>
> Supply the construction arguments for this fragment. This can only be called before the fragment has been attached to its activity; that is, you should call
> it immediately after constructing the fragment. The arguments supplied
> here will be retained across fragment destroy and creation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a proper method in your fragment, something like this:

```
public void receiveURL(String input){
//to handle what you want to pass to the fragment
}
```

And in your mainActivity call you can do something like this:

```
YourFragment fragment = (YourFragment)getSupportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment);
fragment.receive(sharedUrl);
```

Comment: This is a better approach. But, I'm getting a NullPointerException when calling receive method from MainActivity. Any help?

Comment: Is your fragment added in your main activity?

Comment: Can you post the code of your fragment and activity? @nikhil

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you already added the fragment via `fragmentManager.add(..)` so the fragment is already on the layout.

If this is true, then your `AddTab fragobj = new AddTab()` makes no sense since the Fragment already exists.

You need to either store a reference to this fragment in the activity, or use `fragmentManager.findFragmentById()` or `findFragmentByTag()`.

Then follow what Saeed says

Comment: I added the fragment via PagerSlidingTabStrip library. I'm getting a NullPointerException, when I use findFragmentById(). Any help please?

Comment: it's a little more complicated.. they key is in modifying the PagerAdapter, you should probably search for "update fragment in viewpager" or ask another question